# Is this closed under scalar multiplication [vectors]?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am really confused by this vector subspace question:

Determine whether each given set S is a subspace of the given vector space V.

V = R2, and S = {(x,y) -> V | x <= y}

I concluded that 
(0,0) works for zero 
(1,1) and (-1,2) added = (0,3) works for addition
(-1,2) x 2 = (-2,4) works for multiplication because if you multiply a smaller number and a larger number by the same scalar then the smaller number will still be smaller and the larger number will still be larger.

The answer I was given states that this does not pass by multiplication with no examples or proof so I'm kind of lost because this seems straightforward to me. I can't find a combination that this doesn't work for.

Looking for some validation or an explanation before I address this with the professor, thanks.

Comment: $u=(1,2) \in S$ but for $c=-1$, $cu=-1(1,2) \not\in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set does not pass the scalar multiplication test. Consider the vector $(1,2)$, which is an element of $S$. If I multiply this vector by $-1$, I get $(-1,-2)$, which is not an element of $S$. It's multiplication by negative numbers that causes the issue.